# How to get Android Screen over PC's browser?

Tags: java, android, video-streaming

**Goal**: Want to watch my android phone's screen on PC's browser

**Design**: Android app capture the screen(as int[] array),Server deal the screen data to the browser

**Question**: How to change the int array to a stream and play it on browser(I could capture the screen in Android, and pass it to SpringBoot server and print array as String on the browser use SpringMVC ) Please give some advice ,all. I could coding on both Android and JavaEE server. If it is hard for me , simple it, Every UrL request returns a picture of AndroidScreen.

**More Info**:

```
 //on AndroidApp
 public synchronized static int[] getScreenMatrix() {
    try {
        graphics = new FileInputStream(fbFile);


        DataInputStream dStream = new DataInputStream(graphics);
        dStream.readFully(piex);
        dStream.close();

        int[] colors = new int[screenHeight * screenWidth];
        // all is 32bit = 8bit * 4,high 8bit is alpha, then 8bit is red,then green,low 8bit is blue
        for (int m = 0; m < colors.length; m++) {
            int r = (piex[m * 4] & 0xFF);
            int g = (piex[m * 4 + 1] & 0xFF);
            int b = (piex[m * 4 + 2] & 0xFF);
            int a = (piex[m * 4 + 3] & 0xFF);
            colors[m] = (a << 24) + (r << 16) + (g << 8) + b;
        }
        return colors;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use Chrome screencast. See [post by François Beaufort](https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z13xdjt5qx2iur4j104ch1giszacgxuwawk0k). Source code is available at https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/23011021

Comment: @Alex Cohn，I try it ,so cool! Thank you,  I find it's a nice way to display the android chrome's view , is there a way to display common view ? for example: my SMS ,my own app .

Comment: Yet another cool feature (4.4 and up): screen recording to mp4. http://forums.androidcentral.com/android-4-4-kitkat/329674-how-use-screen-recording-android-4-4-kitkat.html

Comment: @AlexCohn Thank you alex, this is what I find.